# TSQL Performance Issues with SYS tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running this script to get list of all objects which can use tables from my find list, this is raw list which later will be feed into `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(Object)`. And I see super low performance, it's never finished, all tables have 2K rows max, is it because using SYSNAME data types maybe or something?

I see problem on that `FindList` join which takes 90% performance. I'm on production grade SQL Server 2016, where I never had any problems. There was dynamic SQL which produce this query, and I'm testing it now as a standalone script, my original join to find table was in first step, it's commented now, I played with different ways, results are same super slow (never finished). Used `LEFT` vs `INNER join` too to try, same thing. Appreciate you leads.

`FindList` table doesn't have any IDX, I think it won't help as I'm using `LIKE` on `JOIN` +  size is small (2K max). DB also small has total 100 objects in `sys.modules`

```
; WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT --TOP 2                     -- 100 rows
        mod.Definition,            
        o.name ObjName, 
        o.schema_id,
        sch.Name Schema_name,
        o.object_id,
        o.type ObjType, 
        o.type_desc ObjTypeDesc 
--       ,x.table_name --, 
    FROM  
        myDB.sys.sql_modules mod
--      INNER JOIN   (SELECT   TABLE_NAME FROM myDB.dbo.FindList  WHERE rn =1) x     ON    mod.Definition LIKE '%'+x.TABLE_NAME+' %' 
    INNER JOIN 
        myDB.sys.all_objects o ON o.object_id = mod.object_id   
    INNER JOIN 
        myDB.sys.schemas sch ON sch.schema_id = o.schema_id  
    WHERE
        o.name LIKE '%'+'0'+'%'            -- this part from dynamic SQL
        OR '0'  = '0' 
),  cte_table AS 
(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM myDB.dbo.FindList  
    WHERE rn =1     -- 2000  rows
) 
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rowNum,
    mod.*,
    x.table_name
FROM 
    cte mod 
LEFT JOIN    
    cte_table x ON mod.Definition LIKE '%' + x.TABLE_NAME + ' %'
```

Estimated execution plan:
[image: Est Plan picture]

Comment: Every  expression that starts with `LIKE  '%... ` is not SARGable

Comment: Which tables are involved in that nested loop join?

Comment: sys.sql_modules will contain many NULL values in the DEFINITION column, which you wouldn't want to do a wildcard LIKE search against.  Maybe eliminate those rows in the CTE definition?

Comment: You could also dump the results to a temp table so you can index it if you're going to do all that other funky stuff

Comment: "Find all references" is something SSDT database projects can do with far more speed and accuracy. If your DB isn't yet under source control somewhere, it's worth considering them. You can even automate searches like this using the DacFX libraries, with no requirement to have an actual SQL Server running, but that does requires familiarity with .NET development.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, Xedni Und tbrookside Und Jeroen, for leads. trying to use SSDT now and get out of NULLS

Comment: @Xedni,do you mean index on findlist.Table_name or  module.definition  in temp.?Definition used with Like%

Comment: I was actually thinking the catalog views (although that was when the correlated subquery was not commented out). Any chance you can include a screenshot of the *full* query plan?

Comment: Thanks X, I will get Plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions like this are a performance killer:

```
mod.Definition LIKE '%' + x.TABLE_NAME + ' %'
```

What you try to do could possible be included in:

```
sp_depends (Transact-SQL)
```

[sp_depends manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

ps: For more detailed answers you will need to provide a query that can execute on any blank system.  (included create table statements etc..)